# Уведомления или так называемые "входящие сообщения"

Tags: предложение, comments, notifications

Всем добрый вечер!

Нельзя ли сделать так, чтобы приходили уведомления об ответах и комментариях не только к своим ответам и вопросам и при определённом способе упоминания меня, а вообще обо всех блоках комментариев, где хоть раз поучаствовал (прокомментировал)?